# Action support on change event conflicts with apex:inputfield on change

Tags: javascript, actionsupport

I am calling javascript function from apex:inputfield and also doing rerendering page same block section Item using action support as I am using depended picklist on my Visual Force page.

but after adding this

```
 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pbsiType" />
```

it has stopped calling my javascript function on change of value event.

Below is the code I am using fro Page block section item

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem Id="pbsiType">
                     <apex:outputLabel value="Type"/>

                        <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Type__c}" id="OppType" onchange="Type('{!$Component.OppType}');">
                             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pbsiType" />
                        </apex:inputField>

                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

and here is the javascript function I am calling from within.

```
function Type(Receivetype){
        SelectedType = document.getElementById(Receivetype).value;
        openLookup();  
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ActionSupport to:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" onsubmit="Type('{!$Component.OppType}');" reRender="pbsiType" />
```

and remove the onchange event from the element

Comment: I cant have that on submit as that also require on onchange event

Comment: Ricky, onsubmit will not launch on submit of the form, it will do onsubmit of the "actionsupport". This means that your JS code will run, and then the re-render is going to happen